# Vue.js Stoplight app - Dynamically changing classes on elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I recently started delving into Vue.js, and decided to try my hand at some custom class/style bindings, so I made a small app that's supposed to cycle through each "light" of a stoplight (red, yellow, green, red, etc.).

My Vue instance has a data property `count`, which is initially set to `0`, and I also have a `setInterval` callout that is to increments the `count` every one second.

Each "light" in the stoplight has a Bootstrap button class associated with it (`btn-danger` for red, `btn-warning` for yellow, and `btn-success` for green), and each class becomes "active" based on some modulus arithmetic against my Vue instance's `count`.

I'm wondering if perhaps I could be handling the change in these classes more efficiently, but am not sure what could be done.

Here is my current code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0,
    styleObject: {
      display: 'block',
      width: '30px',
      margin: '0',
      borderRadius: '50px',
      border: '1px solid black'
    }
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  app.count = app.count + 1;
}, 1000);
```

```css
#light {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id='light'>
    <input type='button' id='red' :class='["btn", (count % 3 === 0) && "btn-danger"]' :style='styleObject' />
    <br />
    <input type='button' id='yellow' :class='["btn", (count % 3 === 1) && "btn-warning"]' :style='styleObject' />
    <br />
    <input type='button' id='green' :class='["btn", (count % 3 === 2) && "btn-success"]' :style='styleObject' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Object Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) to specify the class bindings instead of the [Array Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax):

```
<input type='button' id='red' :class='{"btn": true, "btn-danger": (count % 3 === 0)}'  />
```

That `"btn": true` is okay but a little annoying. Luckily "*it’s also possible to use the object syntax inside array syntax*"<sup>[1](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax)</sup>

```
<input type='button' id='red' :class='["btn", {"btn-danger": (count % 3 === 0)}]'  />
```

The documentation uses double quotes and I attempted to use those but it didn't appear to work - perhaps because `btn-danger` needs to be surrounded by quotes.

```
<input type='button' id='red' :class="[btn, {'btn-danger': (count % 3 === 0)}]" />
```

---

There doesn't appear to be anything dynamic about the styles in `styleObject`, so those can be moved out of the business logic and maintained with the other styles in the CSS section.

---

The interval function could be simplified using the [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()):

```
setInterval(function() {
  app.count++;
}, 1000);
```

---

See the rewritten code that utilizes the advice above.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 0    
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  app.count++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
#light {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#light .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id='light'>
    <input type='button' id='red' :class='["btn", {"btn-danger": (count % 3 === 0)}]'  />
    <br />
    <input type='button' id='yellow' :class='["btn", {"btn-warning": (count % 3 === 1)}]'  />
    <br />
    <input type='button' id='green' :class='["btn", {"btn-success": (count % 3 === 2)}]'  />
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax</sub>